# Multiple SQL Transactions with SCOPE_IDENTITY() in php

Tags: php, sql, transactions, scope-identity

I have a question. I have to Insert over multiple tables. The issue here is, that i need the ID of the first Table in 2 others. 
So i have 3 Tables. Insert on first and then with `SCOPE_IDENTITY` I get the `ID` and have to enter it on the other 2. 
The issue is, that `SCOPE_IDENTITY` gives me the `ID` of the last Insert. So on the 3rd Insert i get the 2nd `ID` instead of the 1st.

Now I try to get the `ID` with a select and save it to a variable. but somehow this does not work.

I use transactions on php. Here is my Code

```
sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn );

    // Set up and execute the first query. 
    $tsql1 = "INSERT INTO CmContainer
                    (CmContainer.Serial
                    ,CmContainer.Valid
                    ,CmContainer.OnBlacklist
                    ,CmContainer.BlacklistingRequested)
                VALUES
                    ('".$userdata['cmContainer']."'
                    ,'1'
                    ,'0'
                    ,'0');"; 


    $cursorType = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql1, null, $cursorType);

    $tsql_ID = "SET @EmpID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
    $cursorType = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt_ID = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_ID, null, $cursorType);

    $tsql2 = "INSERT INTO CmContainerBelonging
                    (CmContainerBelonging.CmContainerID
                    ,CmContainerBelonging.CompanyID)
                VALUES
                    (@EmpID
                    ,'".$_SESSION['userData']['companyID']."')";

    $cursorType = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql2, null, $cursorType);

    $tsql3 = "INSERT INTO CmContainerStatistic
                    (CmContainerStatistic.CmContainerID
                    ,CmContainerStatistic.CreationTime)
                VALUES
                    (@EmpID
                    ,GETDATE())";

    $cursorType = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql3, null, $cursorType);

    if( $stmt1 && $stmt2 && $stmt3) 
    { 
        sqlsrv_commit( $conn ); 
        $lang['successCmRegistration'];
    }else { 
        sqlsrv_rollback( $conn ); 
        error_log('Query error: '.print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        $error .= 'Error on Update!';
    }
```

Somehow i get an error when this is executed. Is it not possible to do this with php or is there an issue with getting the SELECT Result when it is done in an transaction? 
I really have no clue how to make it work.

Thanks in advance for any help i get ;)

Edit: I figured out, that the Variable @EmpID is no longer declared after the tsql_ID has been executed and the next Insert is in a new Statement. Somehow the Variable gets lost here.

Any idea how i can combine the statements correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 $tsql_ID = "SET @EmpID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

To this

```
 $tsql_ID = "SET @EmpID=(SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT);";
```

(ok you dont HAVE to cast it as an int but it helps to explicitly use datatypes)

Comment: I think it might be an issue with php rather than the SCOPE IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 $tsql_ID = "SET @EmpID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

To this

```
 $tsql_ID = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS EmpID;";
```